# Pinescript 2 Alerts for pinescript Connector, my Mission Impossible

Tags: pine-script, alerts

I'm trying my last 2 days to add 2 alerts to a pine script2 indicator for Pine connector. YouTube and google dot worked for me, or I did not find the right site and I tried some things here on your site but I dont get it done. The strategie-tester works fine.

I need this message in the alert.

"alert("LICENSEID,sell,"+syminfo.ticker+",risk=0.10", alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)"

What I'm missing that cant be that difficult, I copied the working string from another indicator  and tried also the "alertcondition(condition, title, message)"

That's not working

```
//Strategy
golong =  crossover(fma,sma) 
goshort =   crossunder(fma,sma)

if (golong)
strategy.entry("My Long Entry Id", strategy.long)
alert("5406404411575,buy,"+syminfo.ticker+",risk=0.10", alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)

if (goshort)
strategy.entry("My Short Entry Id", strategy.short)
alert("5406404411575,sell,"+syminfo.ticker+",risk=1", alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)
```

Im pretty new in TV and Pinescript so please can anybody help?
Johnny

## "Thats the orig code."

```
    //@version=2
//Heikin/Kaufman   by Marco

strategy("Heikin/Kaufman Strategy 


",shorttitle="HAS/KAU",overlay=true,max_bars_back=500,default_qty_value=1000,initial_capital=100000,currency=currency.EUR)
res1 = input(title="Heikin Ashi EMA Time Frame", type=resolution, defval="D")
test = input(0,"Heikin Ashi EMA Shift")
sloma = input(20,"Slow EMA Period")

//Kaufman MA
Length = input(5, minval=1)
xPrice = input(hlc3)
xvnoise = abs(xPrice - xPrice[1])
Fastend = input(2.5,step=.5)
Slowend = input(20)
nfastend = 2/(Fastend + 1)
nslowend = 2/(Slowend + 1)
nsignal = abs(xPrice - xPrice[Length])
nnoise = sum(xvnoise, Length)
nefratio = iff(nnoise != 0, nsignal / nnoise, 0)
nsmooth = pow(nefratio * (nfastend - nslowend) + nslowend, 2) 
nAMA = nz(nAMA[1]) + nsmooth * (xPrice - nz(nAMA[1]))

//Heikin Ashi Open/Close Price
ha_t = heikinashi(tickerid)
ha_close = security(ha_t, period, nAMA)
mha_close = security(ha_t, res1, hlc3)

//Moving Average
fma = ema(mha_close[test],1)
sma = ema(ha_close,sloma)
plot(fma,title="MA",color=black,linewidth=2,style=line)
plot(sma,title="SMA",color=red,linewidth=2,style=line)

//Strategy
golong =  crossover(fma,sma) 
goshort =   crossunder(fma,sma)

if (golong)
strategy.entry("My Long Entry Id", strategy.long)


if (goshort)
strategy.entry("My Short Entry Id", strategy.short)
```

Comment: Please note that the alert() function is available only in pinescript version 4 and above. Update your script to the latest version of the pinescript to be able to use all the features.

Comment: thanks I will try!